# ASP.NET Core6 Health check don't logging exception

Tags: asp.net-core, health-check

I added healthcheck to asp.net core application. When healthcheck is fail - return "Unhealthy", but I can't get any information why it failed. There is no logs - in console, in logger with file. How can i see the error, exception?

I simplified the code for .net6 webapplication

Programm.cs

```
using WebApi6HealthCheck;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Serilog;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console());

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<OneProfileContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlServer("Data Source=fake-dbsql-S2016;Initial Catalog=S7OneProfile;User Id=kos_debugger;Password=SecretPassword;Connect Timeout=3;"));

builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddDbContextCheck<OneProfileContext>(tags: new[] { "live" });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions()
{
    Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("live")
});
app.Run();
```

There is no datebase and healthcheck for dbcontext will fail.
In console I see this image
[image]

References

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
```

UPDATE

If i call dbContext from controller method i see exception in console - and this is right,good,fan. But I want see same exception when call HealthCheck - /health/live

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi6HealthCheck.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
        private readonly OneProfileContext _dbContext;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, OneProfileContext dbContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public string Get()
        {
            var appEvent=_dbContext.ApplicationEvents.FirstOrDefault();

            return "Hello,world";
        }
    }
}
```

GET https://localhost:7197/WeatherForecast
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My  suggestion is below: add logs on Console with .NET Core and Serilog

1.Install the `Serilog`, `Serilog.AspNetCore`, and `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` NuGet packages to integrate the basic functionalities of Serilog.

2.Download the `Serilog.Sinks.Console` and `Serilog.Sinks.Async` NuGet packages to use the Console as a destination of your logs.

3.Update the `Program` class to specify that the application must use Serilog.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().CreateLogger();
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
```

4.Use `ILogger<T>` instead of `Serilog.ILogger`

Since we have bound the Serilog logger to the one native on .NET - the one coming from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` - we can use the native logger everywhere in the project.

Add a dependency to `ILogger<T>` in your constructor, where `T` is the name of the class itself:

```
public class HomeController : Controller

    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Getting random items. There are {AvailableItems} possible values");

            _logger.LogWarning("This is a warning");

            try
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();//you can modify codes to catch your health-check
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "And this is an error");
            }
            return View();
        }
}
```

5.Define the settings in the appsettings.json file instead of directly in the code

```
{

  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Result:

[image]

I find a [link](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console),hoping it can help you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the detailed answer, but i'm so sorry, but the question was not about "How to write logs", but "Why does not write logs inside the HealthCheck". In image from console in this post you can see message "[ERR] Health check OneProfileContext with status Unhealthy", but you can know - why dbcontext is unavailable. In logs there is NO information about it.